How do you calculate edge states with VASP?
I would like to know if anyone knows of a tutorial on how to proceed with this type of calculation. I know it is possible using wannier90+wannier_tools, but I am trying to avoid using it due to time constraints.

Do you just want to show the contribution to the DOS, or do you actually want to visualise the charge density from an edge state?
